# load xml infile query in mysql with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

I have written the below query to insert data from xml file to a mysql table:

```
load XML local infile 'D:\\a.xml' into table asdb.abc rows identified by '<ApplicantName>';
```

It inserts the values in the table. I have a column named AckNo in the `abc` table. I need to insert the xml values where  ackNo is equal to a particular value. e.g. i tried writing the below query but its not working:

```
load XML local infile 'D:\\a.xml' into table asdb.abc rows identified by '<ApplicantName>' where ackNo='1';
```

Would really appreciate someones help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can use a `WHERE` clause with `LOAD INFILE`.

Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html).

I think you have to parse your XML file and keep only values you want, then generates another XML file, before using `LOAD DATA`.

Or easier and quicker :

- Load everything
- DELETE FROM your_table WHERE your_id != "the_value_you_want"